# how to pass value from child window to parent window using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<html>
<head><title>api gateway</title></head>
<body>

<button class="button" onClick="window.showModalDialog('http://localhost.xxxxx');"><span class="icon">Open</span></button>

</body>
</html>
```

---php part---

```
<?php>
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=1;
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
$tweets = "entered into condition";
 echo '<script>window.opener.document.getElementById("result").value = ' .  $tweets . ';window.close();</script>';
exit;
}
```

I'm new to `javascript`. my requirement is when I **click on button** it must `popup` a `new child window` with the `api call`**[which i have done in above code]** but if the user is already `loggedIn` then the popup window must automatically close and display **json** value in `main[parent] window`.

so when i click on button it just opens the child window and its blank and no further change like the window exit or displaying the content in parent window

thanks.

Comment: So matey, what approach have you tried so far? :)

Comment: i dono what approach to proceed dude

Comment: We'd love to see some approaches before providing you with answers. For your question, check out `click()` https://api.jquery.com/click/ and jQuery UI for dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ among with ajax & shorthand methods: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @andy You can check whether user logged in or not in opened page, and put some js accordingly. See my answer for further detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533632/how-to-pass-value-from-child-window-to-parent-window-using-javascript/23533833#23533833)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this scenario;

When user clicks button, you will open a window with url `http://localhost.xxxxx`. In this url, you will check whether user logged in or not.
If user logged in, echo a javascript code to write your json value to parent window, else continue with desired page.

**Parent Window**

```
<html>
<head><title>api gateway</title></head>
<body>

<button class="button" onClick="window.showModalDialog('http://localhost.xxxxx');"><span class="icon">Open</span></button>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Child Window content(`http://localhost.xxxxx` opens in this child window)

```
<?php 
// User logged in
if (!empty($_SESSION["user"])) {
    $valueJson = "somevalue"; // Decide your json value
    echo '<script>window.opener.document.getElementById("result").value = ' . $valueJson . ';window.close();</script>';
    exit;
}

// If user not logged in, go ahead with rendering desired page
```

Comment: hi thanks alot dis is wat i was looking for.. the php part must be written in api or it must be saved in different file?

Comment: You will implement it in API. That code belongs to php file called when you go to `http://localhost.xxxxx`

Comment: session_start();
        $_SESSION['users']; is dis correct

Comment: Use this instead; `if(empty($_SESSION)) session_start();`. If session started, your code will give you warning. If you check session started or not, it will be more eficient

Comment: session_start();
        $_SESSION['user']=1;xxxxxx...;if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
     $tweets = "entered into condition"; echo '<script>window.opener.document.getElementById("result").value = ' .  $tweets . ';window.close();</script>';
      exit;
}

Comment: is the above code correct? my pop window is empty and its not exiting after and value is not passed to parent window :(

Comment: Could you please put your code in your question in formatted way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52265/discussion-between-huseyin-babal-and-andy)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.document.forms[0].getElementById('Txtparent').value = "Value From Popup Page";
```

`window.opener` referred to parent window.

I assume you have one textbox with id **Txtparent**, where you want to set values.

And the text element is under a form. If you need anything else, please elaborate your question a bit more detailed way.

Thanks